# Each element in a list repeated a different number of times

Tags: bash, shell

I have two lists

```
chr=(1 2 3)  # either chr=(1 2 3) or chr=({1..3}) is fine
pos=(2 3 5)
```

and I wanna have the output

```
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 3 
 3
 3
 3
 3
```

1st element of one list is repeated as many times as 1st element in the other list and so on. Outputting to different lines.

I'm trying

```
for i in "${chr[@]}"; for p in "${pos[@]}"; eval printf \"\$i%.0s \" {1..$p};done; done
```

and

```
while read line; do for i in {1.."${pos[@]}"}; do echo "$line"; done; done < chr.list
```

Comment: Whatever you can more easily work with is fine

Comment: Sure. Just did it.

Comment: Oh got it. thxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in ${!chr[@]}; do for j in $(seq ${pos[i]}); do echo "${chr[i]}"; done; done
```

The first loop assigns the indices `0, 1, 2` to `i` (we could also use `${!pos[@]}`).
The second loop takes the value of `pos` at given index and creates a sequence for the repetition (2x, 3x, 5x) 
and prints the value of `chr` at given index.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
for c count (${chr:^pos}) repeat $count printf '%s\n' $c
```